# Failing Over on the Fisrt SQL Server AG at one Location breaks the Distributed AG at the Second Location

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

I have configured a SQL Server Distributed Availability Group (AG), containing a Windows cluster with an AG at one location, and a second cluster with its own AG at another location (thus, two AGs). Everything is working fine. However, upon failing over at the first location from the Primary Replica to the Secondary one in the first cluster/AG (not the Distributed AG), it breaks the Distributed AG, and the node at the other location on the second AG shows as disconnected. Do I need to perform an additional step in order to complete the process?

Thank you. J

Comment: You configured the Distributed AG to use the AG Listener of the main AG?  The remote AG can connect to the AG Listener of the main AG when it's failed over?

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have actually configured a listener for each AG, as per documented at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=automatic

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Just to specify further. No, I have not configured a Listener on the Distributed AG, but only on the two local AGs. According to the link sent in my previous comment, this is how it should be done, no? At least this is how I understood it to be. Thank you again.